# Can we think of an adjunction as a homotopy equivalence of categories?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, adjoint-functors

[There is a way](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64365/natural-transformations-as-categorical-homotopies) in which we can think about a natural transformation $\eta: F \rightarrow G$ as a homotopy between functors $F,G:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$. Now, an adjunction $F \dashv G$ gives rise to "homotopies" $\epsilon:FG \rightarrow 1_{\mathcal{C}}$ and $\eta:1_{\mathcal{D}} \rightarrow GF$, namely the counit and unit. If again we borrow the language of topology, one could say that the existence of an adjunction implies that the two categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ have the same "homotopy type".

Is this a useful picture to have in mind when dealing with adjunctions? Is it well-known?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I meant natural transformation!

Comment: "Is it well-known?" oh yes, algebraic topologists use this all the time!

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks, this is good to know :-)

Comment: [A similar question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1421610/10014)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. An adjunction between two categories gives rise to a homotopy equivalence between their [nerves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerve_(category_theory)).

Also observe that if $I = \{ 0 \to 1 \}$ denotes the interval category, then a natural transformation between two functors is precisely a functor $C \times I \to D$. So natural transformations are like homotopies between functions in this sense, except that they are "directed" in a way that homotopies aren't. This idea gives rise to [directed homotopy theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+homotopy+theory).

Comment: Interesting! I didn't think about the "directed" part of the homotopy. A classical homotopy is symmetric in terms of the two maps involved (in the sense that $f \simeq g \iff g \simeq f$), but a natural transformation between two functors does not necessarily give rise to an "opposite" transformation.

Comment: Yes, that's the important difference. If $C, D$ are groupoids then any adjunction is automatically a natural equivalence (we have removed any directedness, and in fact groupoids are much more closely related to homotopy theory since they model homotopy $1$-types).

Comment: I would say that in general homotopy is not an equivalence  relation, except for nice objects. 
http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.hha/1140012467

Comment: Homotopy, defined in the classical sense for topological spaces using the standard interval, _is_ an equivalence relation, and it is clear that is what the OP is thinking about. (Also note that in the model structure on $\textbf{Cat}$, two functors are homotopic precisely if they are _isomorphic_, not merely linked by a natural transformation.)