# Why is an adjunction a “weak form of equivalence”?

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Wikipedia says:

> An adjunction between categories $C$ and $D$ is somewhat akin to a "weak form" of an equivalence between $C$ and $D$.

I have heard this idea before, e.g. from Qiaochu.

**Can you give an extremely simple example or argument that clarifies the intuitive idea that an adjunction is a “weak form of equivalence”?** I’ve only read some explanations that are technical enough that my intuition doesn’t get that idea.

Comment: Any equivalence of categories induces an adjunction, that might be one reason to call it a "weak" equivalence

Comment: I don't know if that's compelling enough for you but if you have an adjunction $F\dashv U$, then you have natural maps $Id \implies UF$ and $FU\implies Id$, that satisfy some identities that make them "sort of close to isomorphisms". Even without these identities, natural transformations are a first approximation to natural isomorphisms

Comment: @max, my question is essentially, why do those identities mean that they are “sort of close to isomorphisms”? I find it kind of hard to see this. (btw, isn’t an invertible natural transformation by definition a natural isomorphism?)

Comment: The triangle identities tell you that certain morphisms constructed from these natural transformations are identities (see e.g. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/triangle+identities ) : in particular those natural transformations are "sort of close to isomorphisms" (to keep my fake terminology)

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421610/definition-of-adjoint-functor-similar-to-the-definition-of-homotopy-equivalence, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370710/can-we-think-of-an-adjunction-as-a-homotopy-equivalence-of-categories

Answer (score 0):

As the comments have mentioned, there are a few ways to think of this:

1. Equivalences are Adjunctions, but not conversely.
2. The unit/counit are natural isomorphisms if the adjunction is an equivalence.
3. An adjunction is a specific type of bijection between hom sets, or one could say they have the same number of morphisms/size of morphism sets. An equivalence already has this, but the adjunction is weaker but is quite ambient in Mathematics.

Helpful examples would include the forgetful functor $F:\textbf{Grp}\rightarrow \textbf{Set}$, and the free group functor $G:\textbf{Set}\rightarrow \textbf{Grp}$.

**Grp** and **Set** are definitely not equivalent, but there is a one-to-one correspondence between morphism sets defined by the adjunction between $F$ and $G$.